# How to make pyplot.close() work properly in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a lot, at least 10000 plot,
so I use for loop to do it, Here is my code.

```
for i in range(0, 10000):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=0)
    x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)
    
    ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig("test.png")
    plt.close(fig=0)
    
def plot_test():
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=0)
        x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        
        ax.plot(x, y)
        plt.tight_layout()
        fig.savefig("test.png")
        plt.close(fig=0)
```

No matter use plt.close() in function or outside,
The memory is still increasing,
I have checked plt.close("all") and plt.close(fig) are not working too.
Hope anyone can tell me how to use plt.close() properly.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55834853/6366770

Comment: Thank you, however the method in that post are not work for me.

Comment: Given that established methods do not work for you, you may want to provide more information on the environment in which you run (unsuccessfully) your code (jupyter, spyder, you name it).

Comment: After I tried for several methods, I found the memory increasing may be due to I run the code in spyder IDE, when I run in a system terminal, there is no significant memory increasing, even I create new `fig` in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe `plt.close()` is working fine. Your problem is that every plot has the same name. This overwrites any existing file in the directory. Essentially, it creates `test.png` and immediately overwrites it with the every iteration. This solution adds `i` to the end of the plot name and saves to a directory I made called `test`. With this many plots it takes a little bit to finish the iteration

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
# The default backend is "tkinter" which is used for displaying the graphs. 
# "agg" is more lightweight and avoids a tkinter error when making lots of plots
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gc



for i in range(0, 10000):
    # This just shows the progress of the loop
    print(i)
   
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=0)
    x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig("test/test{}.png".format(str(i)))
    plt.close(fig=fig)
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however it does not solve the problem. The problem here is the fig was created, but plt.close() did not close it, therefore in every iteration, a new fig was created again, the memory was taken by fig, I have tried to create fig outside the loop, and in every loop, use plt.cla() to clear ax, it works for me, however, there is a error message : UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations.

Comment: Are you sure `fig` is taking up that memory? The python garbage collector gets rid of it on each iteration. `plt.close` wouldn't affect this behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729249/does-python-garbage-collect-at-the-end-of-an-iteration-in-a-loop

Comment: I am not sure whether fig or other things take the memory, but when I use your code to run, nothing changed, the memory is still increasing, however when I put fig outside the loop, the memory will not increase, therefore, my opinion is that fig took the memory. Have you tried your code?

Comment: Try using `gc.collect()` at the end. Ill update my code for you. Personally I don't see any significant memory increase on my end for either implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I found `gc` does not work for me. Till now, put `fig` outside the loop may be a temporary solution to me.

Comment: Alright, best of luck! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: After I tried for several methods, I found the memory increasing may be due to I run the code in spyder IDE, when I run in a system terminal, there is no significant memory increasing, even I create new `fig` in every loop.